# JS Date incrementation

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

Doing this without libraries.

```
dates.forEach((date) => {
  if(date.getDay() == 6) {
    console.log('sat', date)
    var t = new Date()
    console.log('sat new', new Date(t.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)))
  } else ...
}
```

Gives this output

```
sat 
Date Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
sat new 
Date Sat Apr 02 2022 19:10:27 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

The point of this code is to see if a date is a saturday. If so, increment it towards becoming a work day (i know it says +1 but its a wip)

The result is that the day gets incremented. However for some reason it moves the date towards being in march. I have looked around and apparently this is how you're supposed to do it, but its not doing it.

When I try `console.log('sat new', t.setDate(date.getDate() + 1))` (without new Date()) I get a timestamp of 1646236273249. Which [this site](http://www.unit-conversion.info/othertools/timestamp-to-date/) converts to the 16th of March. Don't know how useful this is.

I hope I gave all the important information here.

Comment: *"Gives this output"*  Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var t = new Date()` - not passing anything to the `Date` constructor will make it "right now".
I think you need to pass the iterated date to the `Date` constructor:

```
dates.forEach((date) => {
  if(date.getDay() == 6) {
    console.log('sat', date)
    var t = new Date(date) // this line
    console.log('sat new', new Date(t.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to increment a day to a given date:

```
date = new Date(date)
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
console.log(date)
```

Comment: Dang, must've overlooked that when I was looking at the examples. Thank you <3